# How to write a synchronous jQuery dialog for validation before submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, form-submit

Here's what I would like to do:

I have a `SUBMIT` button. After clicking the button, the javascript will do some check/validation on my text (such as spelling, uppercase/lowercase). If the check/validation is not passed, then a jQuery dialog will pop-up and confirm with two options:(1) submit anyway (2) cancel (go back to the page and correct some content).

However, I find that the code executes all the script (and skip the dialog's code in the middle), so the dialog's confirmation code executes last and submit anyway. Is there any way to make the dialog's code execute according to its line number? Many thanks!

P.S. I don't want to use the `confirm` because I need the font larger.

Here's the `<form>`:

```
<form name="annotation" id="annotation" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">
</form>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script>
  $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      // Perform some checking/validation
      // ...

      if (!valid) {
        $("#dialog").dialog({width:500,
            buttons: [
            {
              text: "Submit anyway?",
              click: function() {
                // Perform submission
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
            },
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              click: function() {
                // Perform cancelation
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
            }]
        });
      }
      else
      {
        // Perform submission
      }
  });
</script>
```

And the `<div>`:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none"><h4>Are you sure you want to submit this?</h4></div>
```

For example, after I click the button (in the condition of `valid == false`), a very flash showing of the message "Are you sure you want to submit this?" and then the code submit anyway (too fast, I cannot click anything).

Comment: The dialog doesn't stop other code; everything you want to happen after the user deals with the dialog has to be moved inside the button's `click` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help from friend and solved using `document.getElementById('').submit()`. Firstly, change `<input>` to `<button>`:

```
<form name="annotation" id="annotation" method="post">
  ...
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="submit_post()" value="SUBMIT" id="submitBtn">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Then change the script:

```
<script>
  function submit_post()
  {
      // Perform some checking/validation
      // ...

      if (!valid)
      { 
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            width:500,
            buttons: [
              {
                text: "Submit anyway",
                click: function() {
                  document.getElementById('annotation').submit();
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
              },
              {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
              }
            ]
        });
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById('annotation').submit();
      }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `preventDefault()`, like below

```
<script>
  $("form").submit(function(event) {

    var form = event.target;

    if (!valid) {
      event.preventDefault() //Here you can prevent submission
      $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: 500,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Submit anyway?",
            click: function() {
              // Perform submission
              form.submit();
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          },
          {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
              // Perform cancelation
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    } else {
      // Perform submission
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the dialog now can wait. The "Cancel" button works fine, but the "Submit anyway" button cannot submit the content.

Comment: Now give it a try